# Is File.Open directory behavior different in x86 vs x64

Tags: vb.net, x86, .net-4.0, 64-bit, filenotfoundexception

I am working on a application built in VB.Net that allows a document to be uploaded and saved into a database. I did not build this application, but I do maintain it, put enhancements in it here and there. The target framework is .Net4

One of the functionalities within this process when uploading and saving the document it uses the method File.Open() to access the file and run other methods to compress it. The method that uses File.Open takes in a parameter that passes just the filename, not the entire path of where it came from.

When this application is running on an **x64** machine I receive an error (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) when the code hits the File.Open method, complaining that it cannot find the file to open. It is expecting the file to be in the programs executing directory, which does make sense because it is only given the filename to go off, not the entire directory that it came from.

What's getting to me, is that this exact same application (exact same built assemblies) will run fine when run on an **x86** system. It does not fail on File.Open() It still passes just the filename, but somehow, it will know the directory information.

How is this possible?

It's worth noting, that the method that contains the File.Open() method is in a different project in the same solution. It's a referenced DLL. e.g. MyApp.exe (Windows Form Application) references MyUtil.dll (Class Library). I have built against x86, x64 and AnyCPU configurations.

I understand that the fix to this would be to just pass the entire directory to the method, but what I need to know is how this is even possible? I want to better understand why this would happen, and hopefully this would help someone else better understand how assemblies may differ between different system environments.

**EDIT:** Using an absolute path did fix the underlying issue. See the comments below for some good information on this scenario

Comment: `It is expecting the file to be in the programs executing directory` thats a mistake.  Windows has long provided directories for Data like `Users` and `Program Data` and others for executables and still others for Windows system files

Comment: Do a DuckDuckGo search for Windows File System Virtualization.  There are many hits.  Among them is [this one](https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/folder-virtualization-concepts-windows-vista) (picked randomly).  From that link:  _For example, if a legacy application attempts to write to the Program Files directory, UAC silently redirects that operation to an unprotected user-specific folder._

Comment: Are you trying to open the file with write privileges, or just read?

Comment: @VisualVincent Just read privileges.

Comment: @Plutonix when you say its a "mistake" are you referring to the code that has been written, or a windows issue?

Comment: thanks @ChrisDunaway I will check it out

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the application's _**working directory**_, which can be changed easily and for many different reasons. What happens if you try using an absolute path instead? For instance: `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "yourfilenamehere")`

Comment: ...or if you're not using WinForms: `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "yourfilenamehere")`.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. In the end using the absolute path resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has special handling for certain folder names on 64bit systems depending on whether you have a 32bit or 64bit process. Notably, the `Program Files` folder and the `System32` folders map differently depending on what kind of process you have.

Note that this is a difference in *Windows itself*. It's not a behavior that is unique to .Net or Visual Basic. Any program platform that uses Windows native file handling will give you these results.

This is why you should use *appropriate* relative paths or the `SpecialFolders` enumeration, rather than hard-coding full path names, and be careful about where you put things you expect to reference later; you might find they end up in a different location than you expected. Often, the `AppData` or `ProgramData` folders are the more correct location, instead of the `Windows` or `Program Files` folders.